# « Aller à » : faut-il toujours mettre la préposition ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, prépositions, verbes

Exemple :

- Ils peuvent en trouver en faisant leurs courses aux brocantes, aux marchés aux puces, aux magasins d’occase ou aux recycleries.

Est-ce que c’est une bonne phrase, même si l’on utilise « aux » d’une manière répétée ?

Comment: There is no *aller à* in your sentence. Repeating *aux* (and using it in the first place) is not the best choice here.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** La phrase suivante est-elle bonne ?

> Ils peuvent en trouver en faisant leurs courses aux brocantes, aux marchés aux puces, aux magasins d’occase ou aux recycleries.

On ne dit pas « faire ses courses à » ou même « aller à »  suivi d'un (ou plusieurs) complément(s) de lieu au pluriel (donc qui représente(nt) un type de lieu et non un lieu en particulier). Ici on emploierait « dans ».

> Ils peuvent en trouver en faisant leurs courses *dans* les  brocantes, *dans* les marchés aux puces, *dans* les magasins d’occase ou *dans* les recycleries.

*Le bon usage* (Grevisse, 10<sup>e</sup> édition) dit que :

> D'une manière générale, les prépositions autre que *à, de, en* ne se répètent pas, surtout lorsque les différents compléments sont intimement unis par le sens ou qu'ils sont à peu près synonymes.

Pas de règle donc, juste l'usage, disons que c'est une question d'esthétique. On peut répéter « dans » devant chaque complément, je préfère moi ne pas le répéter, la phrase est moins lourde :

> Ils peuvent en trouver en faisant leurs courses dans les brocantes, les marchés aux puces, les magasins d’occase ou  les recycleries.

**2.** Si chaque élément était au singulier, c'est à dire si les compléments représentaient chacun un lieu particulier, on emploierait la préposition « à » pour les introduire :

> Ils peuvent en trouver en faisant leurs courses à la brocante, au marché aux puces, au magasin d'occase et à la recyclerie.

Pourrais-je ne pas répéter la préposition « à » devant chaque complément ? Cet exemple serait un des cas où je répéterais « à », la phrase ne serait pas claire si on ne le répétait pas. Le fait de ne pas répéter « à » entraînerait de fait la suppression de l'article défini devant chaque complément, ce qui, pour peu que la phrase soit dite à l'oral ou mal ponctuée à l'écrit, pourrait faire croire à un unique lieu regroupant brocante, marché aux puces, magasin d'occase et recyclerie.

**3.**  « Aller à » : faut-il toujours mettre la préposition ?

En général oui, parce que le nom qui suit « aller à » est le plus souvent précédé d'un déterminant :

> J'irai à l'épicerie, à la pharmacie et au garage en dernier.

Mais :

> J'irai à Toulouse, Montpellier et Perpignan.

**4.**  Faut-il toujours mettre la préposition « à » devant chaque complément ? Certainement pas.

*Le bon usage* (Grevisse, 10<sup>e</sup> édition) dit que :

> Les prépositions *à, de, en* ne se répètent pas :
> 1º Quand les termes  constituent une locution toute faite :
> — Il se mit *à* aller et venir (Roger Martin du Gard).
> [...]
> 2º Quand les termes représentent le même ou les mêmes êtres ou objets :
> — *À* mon collègue et ami.
> [...]
> 3º Quand les termes doivent être considérés globalement comme désignant un groupe ou une idée unique :
> — Aux officiers, sous-officiers et soldats  — Il importe de bien broyer et mâcher ses aliments (Littré).
> [...]
> 4º Quand ces membres présentent deux noms de nombre joints par *ou* et marquant une approximation :
> — À cinq ou six mètres d'un précipice.

On pourra aussi consulter la BDL : [Répétition des prépositions](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1101), et la page de [ce non spécialiste de la langue](https://rouleaum.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/a-de-et-en-celles-quil-faut-repeter/) qui apporte un œil extérieur et qui finit par conclure que :

> Autrement dit, on peut faire ce que l’on veut, en autant que le texte ne prête pas à confusion.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord sur le (1). Je fais mes courses au supermarché, à la boulangerie... Pour une catégorie plus large comme « magasin d'occasion », j'utiliserais effectivement *dans* mais *à* ne me choque pas.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' N'as-tu pas oublié des mots dans ton commentaire ou bien as-tu mal vu la numérotation ?  Si tu dis que tu n'es pas d'accord sur le (1) on s'attendrait à ce que  ton exemple soit « Je fais mes courses aux supermarchés, aux boulangeries...  » puisque je n'y parle que du cas de compléments de lieu au pluriel. Je traite le singulier (ton exemple) dans le (2).

Comment: Je ne vois pas pourquoi ça serait différent au singulier ou au pluriel.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Alors tu aurais dû mettre un exemple avec des lieux au pluriel, ça aurait été plus clair. Moi j'entends quelqu'un dire « je fais mes courses [obulɑ̃ʒʁi] » à coup sûr je me dis qu'il n'est pas francophone et je lui dis que boulangerie est féminin. Je pense que la différence, pour moi, est question de point de vue. *Faire ses courses à* : se rendre dans un  lieu pour acheter qch (→aller à) on ne se rend que dans un seul lieu à la fois.  *Faire ses courses dans* : être dans des endroits (donc pas de mouvements) où de tels achats sont possibles.

Comment: Je trouve que ce qui est surprenant dans « je fais mes courses aux boulangeries », c'est que c'est inhabituel d'aller dans plusieurs boulangeries. Mais si il y a une boulangerie qui fait des bonnes baguettes et des mauvais croissants, et une autre où c'est l'inverse, je trouve tout à fait naturel de dire « je suis allé aux boulangeries » (et j'ai pris une baguette dans une et un croissant dans l'autre).

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Ouais, exemple extrême quand même. Je ne pense pas que dans la question ce soit ce que le PO veuille dire.

Answer (score 0):

Cette phrase est parfaitement idiomatique, et il faut répéter la préposition *à* en français courant.

On peut aussi ne répéter ni la préposition ni l'article :

> Ils peuvent en trouver en faisant leurs courses aux brocantes, marchés aux puces, magasins d’occasion ou recycleries.

Mais c'est nettement moins courant et très soutenu. En règle générale, on peut ne pas répéter l'article lorsque les termes énumérés sont des variantes d'une même catégorie et que la phrase s'appliquerait aussi à d'autres éléments de cette catégorie (ici, un endroit où l'on peut obtenir des objets usagés). Ce n'est pas une tournure qu'on utilise dans la vie de tous les jours (ça l'était peut-être il y a un ou deux siècles).

Dans le cas général où il y a un article à répéter, je crois que la règle est qu'**on répète la préposition lorsqu'elle est parfois fusionnée avec l'article**. C'est obligatoire si elle change de forme dans au moins un cas (par exemple « à la … et au … »). Ceci fait qu'on répète *à* et *de* la plupart du temps lorsqu'ils sont suivis d'un article défini. On le fait en général même dans les cas où la préposition reste toujours détachée parce que tous les noms sont introduits par *la* ou *l'*.

> Préfères-tu aller à la mer ou à la montagne ?   (Je répèterais le *à*, mais ça ne me choque pas de ne pas le répéter.)

> Est-ce que tu vas à la boulangerie ou au supermarché ?   (On ne peut absolument pas dire <s>« à la … ou le … »</s>)

> Je vais poser la question à un biologiste ou un médecin.   (On peut répéter le *à*, mais ça me paraît lourd et inutile.)

> Ce plat est populaire à Paris, à Dijon et à Lyon.
> Ce plat est populaire à Paris, Dijon et Lyon.
> (Ici je vois une nuance entre les deux phrases. En répétant la préposition, on sous-entend que l'affirmation est vraie dans ces trois ville, et qu'on ne sait pas ailleurs. En omettant la préposition, on sous-entend que la liste est complète dans un certain sens, par exemple parce qu'on a fait un sondage dans dix villes et que ce sont les trois seules où le plat est populaire.)

> J'ai envie de pain et de fromage.   (Si on ne répétait pas la préposition, « pain et fromage » devrait être un plat en soi, ce qui n'est pas le cas.)

> Je ne le connais ni d'Ève ni d'Adam.   (Expression consacrée qui signifie « je n'avais jamais entendu parler de lui ».)

Comment: Bizarre que tu écrives que la phrase est parfaitement idiomatique. Elle ne l'est pas du tout pour moi. On peut bien sûr *faire ses courses aux halles, aux Galeries Lafayette, aux États-Unis ou aux puces*  mais *faire ses courses aux brocantes* ??, jamais entendu et si ça arrivait, je serais très surpris.

Answer (score -3):

Il faut répéter les prépositions « à », « de » et « en » devant chaque complément.

> [wordpress Maurice Rouleau](https://rouleaum.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/a-de-et-en-celles-quil-faut-repeter/)
>
> La règle veut que les prépositions ***à, de, en*** se répètent devant chaque complément. Il faut donc dire : j’ai parlé **à** Pierre et **à** Paul; j’ai eu des nouvelles **de** Lise et **de** Pascal; j’irai **en** Italie et **en* Espagne. On peut, par contre, sans faire de faute, écrire : j’ai visité Ottawa **avec** Lucie et Nicolas;  je suis parti **sans** ma tuque et mes gants; j’ai été bien reçu **par** ses parents et ses amis. Voilà, tout est dit! C’est du moins ce qu’on enseigne.

Note : La référence ci-dessus contient un article très intéressant à propos de l'origine de la règle de cette répétition ;  il sera probablement très apprécié par ceux dont l'intérêt dans la langue française dépasse celui de l'utilisateur courant, mais que le lecteur ne s'attendent pas à découvrir un fondement logique de la règle ; il n'est pas seule autorité, au fil des siècles, qui aura jugé bon d'en formuler un, si seulement il en existe un.

---

La phrase est donc correcte.

Comment: L'article que tu cites dit au contraire que répéter ces prépositions n'est pas toujours obligatoire ! Il y a un grammairien qui a dit que ça l'est, mais d'autres qui disent que ça ne l'est pas. Il faudrait que tu lises au-delà du premier paragraphe. Et même la phrase « C’est du moins ce qu’on enseigne » sous-entend que ce qu'on enseigne (des fois) est faux ou incomplet.